# gem command no longer works after uninstalling RVM using rvm implode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

After failing to get Passenger working with RVM I decided to remove RVM and install use the system gems. I ran

```
rvm implode
```

to remove RVM and also removed the additional files /etc/rvmrc and ~/.rvmrc however now every time I run the gem command I get the following error

```
ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.8.7-p352@rails2'
```

I have started a new terminal session but this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

There's a line you need to remove your .profile or .bashrc, it should look like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Remove that then reload your shell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I've just checked both files and haven't got any rvm references in either.

Comment: It might also be in .bash_profile You can also try doing something like `which gem` to see where the gem command is. Mine is a shell script that tries to load rvm (`cat \`which gem\``) and sends that same message to standard error if it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is additional [instruction for removing rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/#bottom)